# PHP no envia datos a base de datos mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un problema grave que no puedo solucionar, y es que php no envia datos a mi BDD mysqli,
he provado en otros archivos php (fuera del que tengo problemas) y me funciona correctamente.
El codigo esta escrito uno por uno bien:

```html
  <form method="POST">

  <input type="email" id="name" required name="email"  placeholder="Email"/>
  <input type="password"  required name="contraseña" minlength="5" maxlength="20" placeholder="Contraseña (Min.5 Max.20)" >
  <input type="radio" name="recordarme">Recordarme
<div class="recaptcha" data_sitekey="6Le9rHgaAAAAAPa8f40zQ7GKzgL4xyD2Gt-VaW9C" ></div>
  
  <a href="inicio.php"><input type="submit"  name="submit"/></a>
  <a class="yatengo" href="yatengo.php">Ya Tengo Una Cuenta</a>
  <a class="invitado" href="invitado.php">Entrar Sin Registrarse</a>
</div>
</form>

<?php

include ("conexion.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$email = $_POST['email'];
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
$pass = password_hash($contraseña,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$consu = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE email='$email' ";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consu);


if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){

header("location: intentar.html");

}else{

mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO 'registros'(email,contraseña) VALUES('$email','$pass')");

  header("location: registro.html");
  
}


}


?>
```

Cabe recalcar que no uso el action, por que en otros archivos php si me funcionaba bien.
aunque lo use no me funciona de igual manera.

como digo no creo que sea un error de codigo, creeria que el error esta afuera del codigo.

Comment: Una pregunta ¿Ya intentaste cambiar lo que tienes en el if, por lo que tienes en el else? Es que, si se cumple que es mayor a cero, se redirecciona y no hace nada. Y, si no se cumple, al final si inserta. (lo cual es improbable, al menos para este caso).

Comment: Edgar Gc Si, en la base de datos esta vacia, y me inserta con exito dice, pero no me aparece en la BDD.

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero que pases el "INSERT INTO" a una variable, así en caso de que no te funcione correctamente puedas hacer un die($variable) y copies y pegues la cadena en tu base de datos e intentes ejecutarlo.
Otra forma de hacerlo es hacer:

```
mysqli_query(<tu codigo>) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

A simple vista veo que están mal las comillas. El nombre de la tabla va sin comillas y los campos con comillas. Es decir, cambiar esta línea:

```
mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO 'registros'(email,contraseña) VALUES('$email','$pass')");
```

Por esta:

```
mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO registros('email','contraseña') VALUES('$email','$pass')");
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '�a) VALUES('luisicha05@gmail.com','$2y$10$VgxENgWaJsmeuYReA1P/PeYiAzVx.oEsNP88M' at line 1. ESO ES LO QUE ME APARECE.

Comment: Para MariaDB, los campos van sin comillas simples, la tabla tampoco. Fijate en los ejemplos de acá: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert/#examples.

Comment: osea como lo hago?

Comment: mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO registros (email, contraseña) VALUES ('$email', '$pass')"); o bien, mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO registros (email, contraseña) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $pass . "')");

Comment: no amigo, no me funciona, me aparece el mismo error...

Comment: probe de los dos metodos que me enviaste pero no me funciona.

Comment: En otra hoja uso los mismo metodos para conectarme y enviar los datos  y funciona, pero en esta hoja no.

Comment: Probá creando una variable, $variable = "INSERT INTO registros (email, contraseña) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $pass . "')");, debajo escribí die($variable);. Con el resultado que te da la página, copialo y pegalo en MariaDB y ejecutalo a ver si lo ingresa o cuál es el error que te está dando. En caso de que no funcione, copiá tanto el error como el resultado del die()

Comment: amigo, lo intente pero no me sale nada, escribi como vos lo indicas. pero no me sale error nada y aun si no se envia los datos...

Comment: uso mysql en xammp no mariaDB .

Comment: otro detalle es que uso un xampp de 32 bits. para mi computadora que es de 32bits.

Comment: Escribí así: `$variable = "INSERT INTO registros (email, contraseña) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $pass . "')";` y luego `die($variable);`. El resultado llevalo a mysql y ejecutalo. Ahí el error debería ser más claro. Puede que el campo contraseña exceda el límite de caracteres, o que tengas un campo en la tabla que no acepte nulos, etc, etc.